# Mystery regarding for-loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I am stuck with this mystery regarding for loop.

```
    int abc[3], i, j;
    for(j=0; j<3; j++);
    printf("%d\n", j);
    abc[j] = abc[j] + 3;
    printf("%d \n", j);


Output: 

3
6
```

Output should have been 3,3 as I've not changed value of j.

Adding 3 to the jth value of abc has resulted in change of value of j by 3. This happens only while exiting from a for loop and then trying to change the value of abc[j].

Maybe I am missing something pretty obvious. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am getting 3 3 as the output on my VC++ compiler

Comment: What is the array abc initialized to ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a buffer overflow since you declared your array to have size 3 `int abc[3];` yet you are indexing the 4th element; this is **Undefined Behavior**.

```
abc[j] = abc[j] + 3; // j = 3 here, overflow
```

What you are most likely seeing is that `j` is located on the stack just past your array `abc` and so when you overflow one past the array with `abc[3]`, you're actually modifying the memory that contains `j`.

*Note that nowhere in the C standard does it mention the word *stack*, this is an implementation detail and can change from system to system. This is partly the reason why it is **Undefined Behavior** and you are getting responses from people that they see two 3's as output.

Comment: Thank you. It still baffles me why value of j was incremented.

Comment: @primalpop refresh my answer =)

Answer (score 5):

You're indexing past the end of the array (**buffer overflow**) and reassigning other variables on the stack.

```
int abc[3], i, j;
// Your stack looks like this (single 'x' is one byte):
// |abc[0]|abc[1]| abc[2]| j  |  i |
// 
// |xxxx  |xxxx  |xxxx   |xxxx|xxxx|
// 
for(j=0; j<3; j++);
printf("%d\n", j);
// j = 3 at this point
// abc[3] points past the end of the array abc, in this case, at j.
// So the next statement increments j by 3.
abc[j] = abc[j] + 3;
printf("%d \n", j);
```

To verify, try adding the following statements at the end:

```
printf("%d\n", &i == &abc[3]);
printf("%d\n", &j == &abc[3]);
```

**EDIT**

The exact layout of the stack will matter depending on the compiler you're using:

```
misha@misha-desktop:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
misha@misha-desktop:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ ./a.out
3
3
```

Here's why it's working fine on my machine -- the statement:

```
printf("abc: %x abc[3]: %x i: %x j: %x\n", &abc, &abc[3], &i, &j);
```

gives the following output:

```
abc: 4cd0aa70 abc[3]: 4cd0aa7c i: 4cd0aa8c j: 4cd0aa88
```

So the stack is actually:

```
//  aa70   aa74     aa78   aa7c            aa88  aa8c
// |abc[0]|abc[1]| abc[2]|      |  ....  |  j  |  i  |
```

So when it's accessing `abc[3]`, it's accessing `0x4cd0aa7c` which is just "dead space".

Comment: Sorry, it was my first rushed edit.  I deleted it while I went to update, but obviously I wasn't quick enough.

Answer (score 1):

When J = 3, abc[j] refers to 4th element, since, array indexes begin with 0 and not 1. So, you are trying to access a location which is beyond the memory area of the array abc. Coincidentally this location happens to be that of J. Hence, value of J gets modified. Try changing the order of declaration of variables to better understand this behavior.

Thanks,
Vamyip

Answer (score 0):

for(j=0; j<3; j++);

You have a semicolon at the end of the for loop. Problem solved.

Comment: Take a closer look at the question

Comment: A semicolon at the end of a for loop statement is always a bug, either an intentional bug or an unintentional one. Put the semicolon at a line of its own if you intended to use an empty loop. And *if* you intend to use an empty loop, declare the iterator volatile or there is no guarantee that the loop will be executed at all.

Comment: See my first comment as nothing you just said is relevant to the issue at hand.  There is no need to declare the iterator `volatile` in this case because even if the loop is optimized away, that doesn't mean the iterator will have an undefined value.  The compiler will simply assign the constant `3` to the iterator in this OP's case.

Comment: @SiegeX Then why would you write a loop for, instead of just j=3?

Comment: I'm going to guess that the OP wanted to make minimal changes to his existing code while still providing enough that the odd behavior was still present. Most likely he thought the for-loop was relevant, it this case it was not.